# Lazy Load on a dropdownlist menu

Tags: php, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, lazy-loading

I own a doujins website that consists mostly of one drop down menu. The menu has over fourteen thousand options on it. Loading the titles takes a while. Is there a way to make it so that the titles are lazy loaded instead of loading all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Load a default value on load instead of loading all the values... On click of the dropdown, set the inner html to "Loading..." or show a loader, then append the values asynchronously... Let me know if this helps.. This would be a good approach.